# Ajax call not going to function

Tags: c#, jquery

I got this ajax call which transfers a loginname and a score to the code behind.
Problem is it doesn't seem to work... anymore.
it did when I made it but now it decided to stop working and I have no clue why.

Here is the ajax call:

```
$(function () {
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'Game.aspx/Score',
data: JSON.stringify({ gamescore: count_element, loginname: loginname }),
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
dataType: 'json',
})
```

and this is where it goes to (but doesn't):

```
[WebMethod]
    public static void Score(int gamescore, string loginname)
    {
        List<Highscore> Myhighscores = new List<Highscore>();

        string hs = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\temp\hs.txt");
        Myhighscores = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Highscore>>(hs);

        Myhighscores.Add(new Highscore { Score = gamescore, Name = loginname });

        HighscoreHelper.SerializeAndWriteToFile(Myhighscores);
    }
```

Where does it go wrong?

p.s. the list `highscore` contains a public `int` gamescore and a public `string` loginname

Comment: Is there an error in the browser's debugging console?  Does this JavaScript code execute at all?  Is the AJAX request made?  Is the request what you expect it to be?  What is the server's response?  When you debug this code, *specifically* what does it do and where does it fail?

Comment: the javascript code executes for sure, the moment i go into my ajax call it just skips over it, there are no errors in the browser.

it doesnt brake the code it just skips a big part of it.

its supose to send the 2 values to the code behind where i write the 2 values to a txt file using json.

Comment: What do you mean "it just skips over it"?  If the code is executing, then the code is executing.  Check the network tab in the browser's debugging tools to see the result of any AJAX request made.  If it's not being made, then the code is not executing.

Comment: what did you change so that it stopped working?

Comment: No the ajax call isnt being made but that is what i expected becouse when i put a brake point at the function and try to go trough it with F10 it jumps over the ajax call that what i ment with it skips over it

Comment: i didnt change anything thats why im so confused

Comment: Try getting rid of `JSON.stringify` and send in just the `{ gamescore: count_element, loginname: loginname }`. Secondly, get rid of the `dataType`, your `WebMethod` is not expecting to return anything, no reason to have `dataType: json`.

Comment: Is your method decorated with the `[HttpPost]` attribute?